# Why not cover yourself when saying a b'racha in a Mikveh?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mikvah-ritual-bath, parts-of-the-body

From Adam and Chava people started to cover the nakedness of the body. But how come one can say a blessing in a Mikveh while being naked?

Comment: AFAIK, men can't recite a bracha in the mikvah...

Comment: Also while separating Challah https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%91_%D7%92

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate, but it's not: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56497 Some overlapping material.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly enough the Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh De'ah and Remo both feel the same way you do.

See סימן ר - אימתי תעשה ברכת הטבילה, ובו סעיף אחד where it says:

> **א:** כְּשֶׁפּוֹשֶׁטֶת מַלְבּוּשֶׁיהָ, כְּשֶׁעוֹמֶדֶת בַּחֲלוּקָהּ, תְּבָרֵךְ: אֲשֶׁר קִדְּשָׁנוּ בְּמִצְוֹתָיו וְצִוָּנוּ עַל הַטְּבִילָה, וְתִפְשֹׁט חֲלוּקָהּ וְתִטְבֹּל; וְאִם לֹא בֵּרְכָה אָז, תְּבָרֵךְ לְאַחַר שֶׁתִּכָּנֵס עַד צַוָּארָהּ בַּמַּיִם; וְאִם הֵם צְלוּלִים, עוֹכַרְתָּן בְּרַגְלֶיהָ וּמְבָרֶכֶת. ה*גה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁלֹּא תְּבָרֵךְ עַד אַחַר הַטְּבִילָה (טוּר בְּשֵׁם בַּעַל הֲלָכוֹת גְּדוֹלוֹת וְהוּא בה''ג דַּף פ''ה ע''ב וְרַשִׁ''י וְרָאָבָ''ן סִימָן שכ''ח וְש''ד), וְכֵן (א) נוֹהֲגִים שֶׁלְּאַחַר הַטְּבִילָה, בְּעוֹדָהּ עוֹמֶדֶת תּוֹךְ הַמַּיִם, מְכַסֵּית עַצְמָהּ בְּבִגְדָהּ אוֹ בַּחֲלוּקָהּ, וּמְבָרֶכֶת.* ‏

Essentially, the Shulchan Aruch says they should either make the Bracha before disrobing, or at least churn the water before making the Bracha, if the water is lucid.

The Remo suggests to make the Bracha after dipping, while still in the water, but after covering themselves with a garment.

However, the Be'er Heitev says that nowadays the women make the Bracha in the Mikva while looking away from their body, or while hugging themselves, so as to create a partition between their upper & lower body.

> **באר היטב**  (**א**) נוהגים. כתב הט''ז אפשר שבימי רמ''א נהגו כן אבל עכשיו אין נוהגים כן וגם אנו שמענו שהנשים אינן נזהרין אפילו בחיבוק ידים בהפסקה בין לב לערוה ונראה שגם זה אליבא דהלכתא אלא **שלכתחלה יש לעשות חיבוק ידים** דאין פקפוק על זה עכ''ל וכ''כ הש''ך **דנשי דידן מברכות במים צלולים ועיניהם חוץ למים ומנהגן תורה היא** עכ''ל (ושל''ה כתב אנשי מעשה יזהירו לנשותיהן שיטבלו ותברך ואח''כ תטבול שנית): ‏

This based on the Halacha (documented in Orach Chaim in סימן עד - שלא לברך כשאיבריו רואין את הערוה) that a woman may make a Bracha while undressed if she hugs herself or is sitting, as her private parts are then not visible to herself.